# how two phase commit ensure serializability

Tags: database, transactions, distributed-transactions

Two phase commit is used in distributed transaction. For example, a client sends a transaction to two databases with a coordinator.

- step1: client get a global transaction id from coordinator
- step2: client send the transaction to two databases respectively
- step3: client send the commit flag to coordinator
- step4: coordinator send prepare flag to two databases, and two databases response prepare ack
- step5: coordinator send commit flag to two databases, and two databases response commit ack
- step6: coordinator response commit ack to client

My questions are

- What is the global transaction id in step1 used for?
- And two phase commit is used to ensure the atomic in ACID, but how does it ensure the serializability? For examples, if client A sends transaction A and client B sends transaction B to databases simutaniously, then two databases may execute two transactions in different orders. Then two databases may end with non consistent states.

Answer (score 1):

The global transaction id in step one is globally unique.
To insure the atomicity, 2pc uses blocking when the coordinator is not available.

I was reading some about it here:
https://ebrary.net/64874/computer_science/coordinator_failure